# Finding out the script causing MySQL failed connections

Tags: security, mysql

I see lot of lines in mysql.log

> Connect   Access denied for user 'M'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I am sure I don't have such a user on my system. I need to figure out what script is attempting those connections so I can figure out wheter it is a misconfiguration or a rogue process trying to break in.
As an experiment, I create the user M at localhost to see what happens, I got this in my logs

> 150129  8:50:10   221 Connect   M@localhost on
>
> ```
>              221 Quit
> ```

and thus it isn't shown in the processlist either.